# Percussive non-tonal Note in Melodic Staff

Tags: lilypond

Would like to make the final note in this passage non-tonal, like and x with a stem, or percussive note:

```
\times 2/3 { gis gis gis } gis4 cis |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a note head x-shaped you can use an override. In your example that would be:

```
\times 2/3 { gis gis gis } gis4 
\once \override NoteHead.style = #'cross
cis |
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with the `\xNote{}` command or `\xNotesOn` and `\xNotesOff`. See the appropriate section of the documentation: [§1.1.4 Note heads](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/note-heads):

```
c4 b
\xNote { e f }
c b < g \xNote c f > b
```

[image: x-notes in lilypond]